# Как в Gson исключать параметр в сериализации в зависимости от условия?

Tags: java, android, gson

есть параметр Нужно чтоб в зависимости от условия он сериализовался в `json` или не был там вообще.Как такое сделать в Gson

Comment: Если поле не примитив и равно `null`, то `Gson` не сериализует его - это поведение по умолчанию. Если у Вас не так - посмотрите методы билдера.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [ExclusionStrategy](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html), а можно написать свой [сериализатор](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html).